# How to get the roles of the referred user

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have created `User` class with some relationships. also want to get the relationship `REFERRED_BY` where developing relationship with the already existed user.

I have used the query to get the user who are connected with each other but it is not returning the roles of the user.

```
 MATCH (u:User)-[:REFERRED_BY]-(myMembers:User) 
 WHERE ID(u) = {0}
 RETURN myMembers
```

Comment: Does id exist into the system?

Comment: Yes passing relevant Id which returns us the user node also but only the role is not returning which is in User class
@Relationship(type = "ROLE_TYPE", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private List<Role> role;

Comment: It is spelled corrently at the top of your question but in your query it is mispelled.
Can you try this? `CALL db.relationshipTypes() YIELD relationshipType
WHERE relationshipType = 'REFFERED_BY'
RETURN relationshipType`

Comment: Are the "roles of the user" in a node with a different label e.g. `:Role`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not look for any `ROLE_TYPE` relationships and only returns users, so it will not return any roles.

Assuming that your DB uses the `REFERRED_BY` spelling (and you *really do not care about the direction* of that relationship), your role nodes have the `Role` label, and you are looking for the roles of the `myMember` nodes, then this should return a list of roles for each `myMember`:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:REFERRED_BY]-(myMember:User)-[ROLE_TYPE]->(r:Role)
WHERE ID(u) = {0}
RETURN myMember, COLLECT(r) AS roles
```

Note: if some `myMember` nodes can have no roles, then this should be used instead if you want to see all `myMember` nodes:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:REFERRED_BY]-(myMember:User)
WHERE ID(u) = {0}
OPTIONAL MATCH (myMember)-[ROLE_TYPE]->(r:Role)
RETURN myMember, COLLECT(r) AS roles
```